# Convergence of absolute value does not imply convergence of function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

In real analysis we showed that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)|=|L|$, then not necessarily $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ (the converse is true).

I want to find a counter example in complex analysis, i.e, if $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=|L|$, then not necessarily $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=L$ (the converse is true).

The proof that the converse is true used the inverse triangle inequality, as $$\Big||f(z)|-|L|\Big|\le |f(z)-L|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |f(z)|\longrightarrow |L|$$

Please help me find a proper counter example. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=|-L|=|L|$. So which one to converge to $L $ or $-L$?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let $f$ be *any* continuous (at $z_0$) function with $f(z_0)\ne 0$ and let $L=-f(z_0)$.

Comment: I tried to find such function before, but to no avail.